# How is "error time" calculated from SiteScope logs?

Tags: logging, monitoring, analysis, sitescope

I have the raw logs from a SiteScope installation, but I am unable to understand how the "error time" is calculated.  The Quick Reports give a certain "error time", but I am unable to match it.

I have tried:

- Adding up the time from the "error" status to the next log entry
- Adding up the time to each "error" status from the previous log entry
- Adding up the time to and from each "error" status
- Doing the above, but subtracting "disabled" time from total time (denominator)

My SiteScope version is 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Normal "error" time is calculated by taking the timestamp for each row with an "error" status and subtracting the timestamp of the previous row.  All of the differences are summed, and then divided by the difference of the latest timestamp and the earliest timestamp.

Best case "error" time is calculated by taking the timestamp for each row with an "error" status and subtracting it from the timestamp of the next row.

These calculations are performed on a per-monitor basis.  If calculating from raw logs, filter out rows that are not statuses of the given monitor.  Valid statuses are "good", "error", "disabled", and "warning."